# Big O Time Complexity for nested loops

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, big-o

What is the time complexity for the below code?

```
int i = 0;
while(i*i <=N) {
  for(int j = 0; j <=N; j++) {
    for(int k = 0; k <=N; k++, i++) {
      //O(1) operation
    }
  }
i++;
}
```

In nested loops if the outer loop 1 takes O(1) time and inner loop 2 takes O(logn) time and inner loop 3 takes O(n).
Then the total T.C. is O(1)O(logn)O(n) = O(nlogn). Is it true?

Please explain.

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr: This code runs in `O(n^2)`.

Detailed answer:

The outer "loop": `while (i*i <= M)` is a distraction.

Because `i` increases itself for each iteration of the most inner loop - it means by the time you re-evaluate the condition in it, the value of `i` is going to be `N*N`. This means, the outer loop is always repeating itself only once.

Now, once you ignore it, it is easy to see that the time complexity of the remaining code is `O(N^2)`, since it's basically can be rewritten as:

```
int i = 0;
if (i * i <= N) {  // Since the while loop does not repeat more than once
  for(int j = 0; j <=N; j++) {
    for(int k = 0; k <=N; k++, i++) {
      //O(1) operation
    }
  }
  i++;
}
```

---

<sub>Note: This answer assume no overflows of the variables, and specifically `i` does not overflow</sub>

Answer (score 0):

> Big O Time Complexity for nested loops

The operation "`//O(1) operation`" is executed `(N+1)^2` times. And the number of times the calculations done by the loops themselves (e.g. performing the test `j<=N`) is also square (`N^2+a*N+b`).

So the time complexity is `O(N^2)`.

You can test that by extending your program the following way:

```
int i=0;
int count=0;
while(i*i <= N)
{
    for(int j=0; j<=N; j++)
    {
        for(int k=0; k<=N; k++, i++)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    i++;
    printf("i after the while() loop: %d\n",i);
}
printf("Number of steps: %d\n",count);
```

You test your program with different values of `N` and you can see that:

- `i` is `(N+1)^2+1` after the first pass of the `while()` loop. This means that the condition `i*i<=N` is equal to `(N+1)^4 + 2*N^2 + 3*N <= (-2)`. And this is always false for `N>=0`.
- The operation `count++` (representing ourt `O(1)` operation) is done `(N+1)1^2` times.

> Time Complexity

Such kind of questions are typically asked on the [CS Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com) web site, not on StackOverflow.

StackOverflow is intended for questions about writing computer programs only.

(Note that StackOverflow is part of the StackExchange network and you can use all [StackExchange web sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#) with your user account.)